# A new seven-words puzzle!

Tags: wordplay, word-square

These tend to be as much fun to make as they are to solve.

Each of the "words" are seven letters long and form a square that reads the same down as it does across.

You know, like this ancient one: 
SATOR 
AREPO 
TENET 
OPERA 
ROTAS

But this one is seven letters!

1: What puzzle would be complete without THIS homage to Wonder Woman! 
2: This is an anagram for Hum Ion Z, but makes no sense. 
3: This is the Giant of Africa. 
4: This used to be a popular way to sort out disagreements but wasn't really very civilized. 
5: This evil, destructive one should eventually be defeated by Ahura Mazda (we hope). 
6: This word is one quap short and spelled backwards. 
7: Supporters of Net Neutrality would like to see one of these with an arta.

Comment: Pedantic: this is a word square, not a sator square. A sator square has to read the same up-down, left-right, down-up and right-left. These are a right pain to do in English.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This one required a lot of Googling!

My answer:

> ```
>  B O N D A G E
>  O Z I U H N M
>  N I G E R I A
>  D U E L I N G
>  A H R I M A N
>  G N I N A L A
>  E M A G N A C
> ```

Explanation:

1: What puzzle would be complete without THIS homage to Wonder Woman!

> I assume that **BONDAGE** is a reference to her Lasso of Truth.

2: This is an anagram for Hum Ion Z, but makes no sense.

> The anagram is **OZIUHNM**, and indeed makes no sense.

3: This is the Giant of Africa.

> **NIGERIA**'s nickname is "The Giant of Africa".

4: This used to be a popular way to sort out disagreements but wasn't really very civilized.

> People used to sort out disagreements by **DUELING** (American spelling).

5: This evil, destructive one should eventually be defeated by Ahura Mazda (we hope).

> Ahura Mazda is the main entity in Zoroastrianism, and **AHRIMAN** is the evil spirit defined by Zoroastrianism.

6: This word is one quap short and spelled backwards.

> Take the word **aquaplaning**, remove the "quap", and reverse it to get **GNINALA**

7: Supporters of Net Neutrality would like to see one of these with an arta.

> The want an **e-Magna-Carta**.  Without the "arta", it becomes **EMAGNAC**.

Comment: Wow, nice. I better try harder to make them ungooglable next time!